# Tree-like Connectors in Table (HTML/CSS/Prototype)

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototypejs

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DmcEB/54/

I'd like it to looks like this:

[image]

The code should be smart enough to know that it should only create connectors for the rows after the event pick and before the game date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Edit**] code adjusted to allow for 'lastindent' within the table.

```
var lastCell,remember;
$$('.geniusPicks tr > td:first-child').slice(1,-1)
     .each(
       function(cell) {
         cell = $(cell);
         lastCell = (cell.innerHTML.match(/^@/)
                ? cell.addClassName('indent') 
                : void 0);
        if (remember &&
            remember.innerHTML.match(/^@/) && 
            !cell.innerHTML.match(/^@/)) {
           remember.addClassName('lastindent');
        }
       remember = cell;
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yU6N/)

Comment: That's pretty close. Instead of looking like this, though: http://bit.ly/iXaKZ3. I'd like it to look like this: http://bit.ly/jnUve0. I tried a couple things but couldn't quite get it.

Comment: Hi keruilin, I've edited my answer, giving the function some memory. Try it out and tell me what you think.